# VueJS: Deployment with .env variables shows env variables in app.js file

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables

I'm new to VueJS and trying to deploy an admin dashboard over at Digital Ocean, but I'm confused how to deploy a VueJS app without showing the .env variables in the compiled app.js

My login details are stored in a `.env` file, and I use the `vue-auth` library to have a login panel (among other things).

My `.env` file:

```
EMAIL=test@admin.com
PASSWORD=justpassword
```

When I run `npm run build`, these crendentials from .env are imported in the compiled app.js file (`/dist/app.js`) and are visible in the HTML source code.

My compiled `app.js` file has this information:
      acceptedFiles:Object({NODE_ENV:"production",_EMAIL:"test@admin.com",_PASSWORD:"justpassword"})

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think [envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify) should resolve your issue, but I'm not quite sure. You can give it a try.

Comment: [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) will do the job